# Javacv Face Recognition in Android: dlopen failed: library libopencv_legacy.so not found

Tags: android, face-recognition, javacv, google-code

I am trying face recognition in Android using JavaCV (google-code).

It is showing this error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "../../lib/libopencv_legacy.so" not found

Other libraries like `libopencv_highgui.so`, `libopencv_core.so`, `libopencv_contrib.so` are working well, but when I add the code for face recognition it shows the error that I mentioned above.

Details:

- Android Studio: 3.1.3
- javaCV: 0.7
- ndk version v20

I put `abiFilters` in gradle as:

```
ndk{
   abiFilters "armeabi","armeabi-v7a"
}
```

Stored all `*.so` files in "armeabi" and "armeabi-v7a" directories

When I try to add the Face Recognizer code:

```
FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
```

the it shows this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "../../lib/libopencv_legacy.so" not found
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "../../lib/libopencv_legacy.so" not found
```